# return the n largest/smallest values in pandas dataframe where many rows contain same values

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering how to return the rows containing n smallest values in a dataframe df that looks like this.

```
id           xx             count
1            A              1
2            B              1
3            C              3
4            D              2
5            E              3
6            F              10
7            G              11
8            H              17
```

Say I want to find the rows containing the 3 smallest counts (in this case, the 3 smallest counts are 1,2 and 3). So, I want the answer to be like this:

```
id           xx             count
    1            A              1
    2            B              1
    4            D              2
    3            C              3
    5            E              3
```

If I simply sort the dataframe based on count and use `df.nsmallest(3, 'count')`, it would only return the first three rows of the desired dataframe. But I want all rows that contain the 3 smallest counts. Is there any simpler way to do this in pandas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) with [`nsmallest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nsmallest.html) for finding values and then [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
s = df['count'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(3)
print (s)
0    1
3    2
2    3
Name: count, dtype: int64

print (df[df['count'].isin(s)])
   id xx  count
0   1  A      1
1   2  B      1
2   3  C      3
3   4  D      2
4   5  E      3
```

Another solution with [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html), sorting by [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) (because output of `unique` in `numpy array`) and selecting first 3 values:

```
arr = np.sort(df['count'].unique())[:3]
print (arr)
[1 2 3]

print (df[df['count'].isin(arr)])
   id xx  count
0   1  A      1
1   2  B      1
2   3  C      3
3   4  D      2
4   5  E      3
```

Comment: You are truly amazing @jezrael!!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution - using [rank()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) method:

```
In [43]: df[df['count'].rank(method='dense') <= 3]
Out[43]:
   id xx  count
0   1  A      1
1   2  B      1
2   3  C      3
3   4  D      2
4   5  E      3
```